# Is there a way to make IETab always open a site in Internet Explorer?

Tags: firefox-extensions, ietab

IETab offers a setting that lets you define sites that should always be opened using IE's rendering engine. This is great and I use it all the time.

There are a few sites, though, with which I encounter problems when I access them this way (needless to say that these have some IE-only features, otherwise I would simply use Firefox without IETab). So my question is: is there a way to make IETab (or any other extension that does the same thing) automatically open a specific list of sites in IE?

**To be clear:**

I want a way to specify a list of sites that will open an external IE process from Firefox, when clicking on those links or bookmarks from within Firefox.

Comment: OK, I can't find a way to do what you want.  I'll edit your question to clarify and remove my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think IE Tabe Lite will do this for you:
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/ie-view-lite/